# MonoRail BindObject() equivalent in ASP MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I need to do late binding of a complex type with DataAnnotations within an Action if condition X is true. I cant bind everything up front in the method params as a couple of them will not exist unless X == true so Model.IsValid will be false (since it tried to bind non existant params) due to validation failing on the complex type.

MonoRail solved this by allowing you to [manually bind](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Controllers-Data-Binding&NS=MonoRail#BindObject_and_BindObjectInstance_11) when needed, this is the exact scenario i have so im wondering if theres something similar available in MVC3?

I cant overload the Action as it blows up with an ambiguous call, i cant post to a different action as the form is all dynamic content, so i see the only alternative is rolling my own validation / binding mechanism pulling out data annotations to validate with.... boooo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the [ControllerBase.TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460189%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method (it has a lots of overloads).
You can use it similarly like `BindObject`:

Some model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateModel(bool? acceptedConditions)
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    if (acceptedConditions ?? false)
    {
         if (TryUpdateModel(model))
         {
             //Do something when the model is valid
         }
         else
         {
             //Do something else when the model is invalid
         }

    }   
    return View();
}
```